# How to make xml out from text inside a text file in php

Tags: php

How to make xml out from text inside a text file in php?
I have a code but it brings me error "Extra content at the end of the document".

Below is my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
$lines = file('file.txt');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
foreach($lines as $line){
   $output = '<url><loc>http://example.com/'.$line.'.html</loc></url>';
   echo $output;
}
```

here is example text file:

```
page1
page2
page3
page4
```

sample output:

```
<url>
   <loc>http://example.com/page1.html</loc>
</url>
<url>
   <loc>http://example.com/page2.html</loc>
</url>
<url>
   <loc>http://example.com/page3.html</loc>
</url>
<url>
   <loc>http://example.com/page4.html</loc>
</url>
```

I will need to use these for sitemap.xml

Comment: `file()` is only meant to read, it doesn't give you a file handler to write in it. Concatenate your output, and `fwrite` it back in your file

Comment: A couple of things you need to consider: the code you have does not generate a valid XML file: you forgot to add the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` tag, for example. Running this script will, indeed, output an XML string, but won't write it to a file, for that, you'll need `fwrite` or `file_put_contents`. Though the markup is quite simple, it is considered safer to build a DOM using the correct tool (`simpleXML` or `DOMDocument`), instead of stringing it together, which is error-prone

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem can you show me how? cause im really a beginner. Hope you understand my situation.

Comment: @pmescorido: I understand your position, and empathize with it. But just spoon-feeding you the answer isn't going to help you to actually _understand_ things. I'd urge you to look at the documentation for the classes I mentioned, and try it out yourself first. If you're stuck along the way, update this question and I'll do what I can to help. Hope you understand where I'm coming from

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem ok let me try if i can do, and thank you

Comment: @pmescorido: Noticed what error you're getting, it's an easy fix. Since you took my previous comment so well (last time I recommended someone to try something themselves first, I got called a lot of names, none of them were flattering ;-P), I've taken the time to write up an answer. Still: I would urge you to write the sitemap to a file somewhere, and possibly get acquainted with a DOM parser of sorts

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem it brings me new error "Encoding error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML error *"Extra content at the end of the document"* is quite simple. By definition, a valid XML DOM must have one, and only one, single root note, which contains the entire dataset. You don't have this. Your output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<url>
   <loc>http://example.com/page1.html</loc>
</url>
<url>
   <loc>http://example.com/page2.html</loc>
</url>
<url>
   <loc>http://example.com/page3.html</loc>
</url>
<url>
   <loc>http://example.com/page4.html</loc>
</url>
```

Whereas valid XML would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <sitemap>
        <url>
            <loc>http://example.com/page1.html</loc>
        </url>
        <url>
           <loc>http://example.com/page2.html</loc>
        </url>
        <url>
           <loc>http://example.com/page3.html</loc>
        </url>
        <url>
           <loc>http://example.com/page4.html</loc>
        </url>
    </sitemap>
```

So the simple fix in your case would be:

```
header('Content-type: application/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemap>';
$lines = file(
    'file.txt',
    //do not line-breaks to XML values, and skip empty values, to avoid empty tags
    FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES
);
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    echo '<url><loc>http://example.com/', $line, '.html'</loc></url>';
}
echo '</sitemap';
```

But really, I'd recommend you think about how to best structure your DOM, and how you can use DOM parsers to reliably construct the markup. And after that, I'd strongly recommend you *write the file to disk*, instead of generating it every single time you need it.

Comment: oh really tnx, the "Extra content at the end of the document" solved but brings me new error "Encoding error"

Comment: @pmescorido: That's because PHP uses UTF-8 encoding, but XML's default encoding is `ISO-8859-1`. Just add an `encoding="utf-8"` attribute to the xml tag (see updated answer), and you should be home free, unless it's the other way around... I always have to look that up. Ah well, just play around with the encoding attribute

Comment: I have try your code but brings me blank page. I think you miss something i never see. Please check it again.

Comment: @pmescorido: check the source of the page, XML markup does not show up in some browsers...

Comment: @pmescorido: Set error reporting to -1 (or `E_STRICT|E_ALL`) and set `display_errors` to 1, you should be able to see what the error is. Also: make sure there is no output whatsoever prior to calling `header()`. This includes any whitespace at the top of your script: `<?php` is ok, but ` <?php` is not (the latter has a space before the `<?php` tag). Also try running the script from the command line, and check the raw output: `php script.php > out.xml`, the `out.xml` file should contain all output

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) in php  to write into file

Comment: not to make a new xml, i mean it will output a xml when i visit the php file

Comment: use echo it will work I guess because print is only for debugging

Comment: @AdityaShankerTagirisa: `print` is only for debugging? What are you smoking? `print` is just as valid as `echo` is. Saying it's for debugging is like saying a computer's speakers are only there for warning noises...

Comment: @Aditya Shanker Tagirisa tnx i used echo and it work, but brings me new problem, i have updated the question.

Comment: @AdityaShankerTagirisa: [RTFM](http://php.net/print), there's nothing in there about `print` being debugging. `print` is _a language construct_, just like `return` or `echo` is. Language constructs cannot be disabled. End of. `print` merely passes its argument to the output stream. nothing debug-specific about it. Disabling `print` will require you to build your own fork of PHP... it is not possible with php as-is. No way, not going to happen...